# java.net.MalformedURLException: Illegal character in URL

Tags: java, url, character, urlencode

I am working on struts.I am encrypting password in one application and passing encrypted password to another application through open url connection.Some times this works fine if i click on the link again system is throwing "java.net.MalformedURLException: Illegal character in URL".Please help me.

Comment: An edited section of code would really help solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Are you URLEncoding the password?

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html